# Uploading a png file to Azure Blob Storage is losing transparency

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

We are having some difficulty to figure out how upload `png` files to Azure Blob Storage without losing image transparency.

We are using the Azure's Storage SDK with the code below:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(*blob_connection_string*);

//create client to work with blobs
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

//already created container via azure management portal, set container reference
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("brand");

foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
{
    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(postedFile.FileName);
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(postedFile.InputStream);

}
```

We've tried force the ContentType property before upload like this:

```
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/png";
```

But doesn't work neither with or without this property.

Comment: Azure Blob Storage is a simple object store so your image file should not change. Can you please share the link to the original file and the file in blob storage?

Comment: Can please you verify first, Stream: postedFile.InputStream is valid by writing to a local file.

Comment: This is the uploaded file: https://c5ecommercedevstorage.blob.core.windows.net/brand/1-dove.png The original file is any file on google images in png format with transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for those who are experiencing this issue, we've found a solution:

The problem was with using Microsoft .Net Image object. According MSDN this object work only with PNG 32 bits:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1kcb3wy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255

We've changed the upload routine to get the posted file binary direct from the input and work like a charm!

Thanks again for the ideas who drive us to this solution!

Hugs